# Upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10 results in Lag

Tags: cpu, 17.10

The loading speed of my desktop seems to have drastically lowered. I tried looking at the processes to see what the issue was but couldn't find anything that was hogging cpu processing power.

It seems that Ubuntu 17.10 lags a lot after installation.

Has anyone been able to source the cause of this lag?

**EDIT:** The lag issue seems to have solved itself. Not idea what caused it or what fixed it. Others might experience this in the future too!

Comment: What does `top` say? What do your logs say?

Comment: %CPU                                                                           
**14.8** gnome-shell                                                                        
**2.6** gnome-terminal-  As you can see in bold, there isn't much cpu usage happening (but I'm still getting lag).

Comment: Do you get the same lag when booted from a LiveUSB?

Answer (score 1):

To source the cause you can reduce the causes:
the upgrade to 17.10 make wayland as default display manager... try to log with Xorg insted from the login screen select the cogwheel icon.
Also check if with the previous kernel you still having lag.
Also hit esc during  boot to see if you have some error and launc your apps from terminal to check if you get warnings or errors from there.